# Update multiple documents in mongodb in one go

Tags: mongodb

I'm still in the middle of getting familiar with mongoDB queries so my problem might be very easy for you guys.

The problem is -
I have a document as shown in 'document.jpg'

[document.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9S0z.jpg)

Both of these documents are having one entry '5ac649444f3df45be852df84' under their products array. I want to remove this entry. I have the name of these two documents in an array and also have this entry '5ac649444f3df45be852df84' -

arr = ['andwived', 'QA Infotech']

productId = 5ac649444f3df45be852df84

Now the query I am using is -

```
enter code here
productId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId)
Org.update(
    {
        'name':{"$in":[arr]}
    },
    {
        $pull: {'products': productId}
    },
    callback
)
```

This is not giving any error but not removing the mentioned id either. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
const productId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ac649444f3df45be852df84');
const arr = ['andwived', 'QA Infotech'];

Org.updateMany(
{
    name: {$in: arr}
},
{
    $pull: {products: productId}
},
    callback
);
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked. @Igal, can you please suggest when should we use quotes and when we should not? Or we need not to use them at all?

Comment: your issue came from passing $in an array inside brackets, thus an array with an array in slot 0. the operator probably tried to compare Org names (which are probably strings) to an array object.